# Accessing /me in MS Graph API via msgraph-sdk-python-core

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to hit the `/me` endpoint in MS Graph API via the [msgraph-sdk-python-core](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core) library. The request works via the Graph Explorer, but now I'd like to use code. I'm just trying to replicate the exact same request they show in that README.md:

```
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

browser_credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID')
client = GraphClient(credential=browser_credential)
result = client.get('/me')
```

However, instead of using the `InteractiveBrowserCredential`, I need to use something that is not interactive. The [azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) library contains, for example, the `UsernamePasswordCredential`, `OnBehalfOfCredential`, etc. but I'm not sure which I should use.

I've tried a couple of different things, which have resulted in different errors. The underlying issue may ultimately be that the app has not been configured properly in Azure by IT. Perhaps they need to activate the app as a "public client" or similar. However, before I ask IT to continue messing around in Azure, I would like to confirm what my code should look like.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MFA enabled in your Azure AD tenant then you can't use `UsernamePasswordCredential` or `OnBehalfOfCredential` , you will have to use `ClientSecretCredential` for a non interactive method but you can't call `/me` endpoint as you will be authenticating with your ***AzureAD App*** that you have configured for using to call the Graph API's and also you will need to provide the ***required permissions in API permissions Blade*** of your ***App Registration***, the same way you provide in Graph Explorer.

If you don't have MFA enabled , then you can use the two non-interactive methods.

---

[image]

**ClientSecretCredential:**

I am testing to get the details of all the users , so I have provided `Directory.ReadWrite.All` to the above app and used the below code:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient


credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id='e186e64a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',client_secret='L~I7Qxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',client_id='1be5d8ab-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx')
client = GraphClient(credential=credential)
result = client.get('/users')
print(result.json())
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** In this method `/Me` can't be called , you will get the below error :

[image]

---

As ***UsernamePassowrdCredential*** is not recommended by Azure and you will have to use ***[OnbehalfOfCredential](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/08/understanding-azure-ads-on-behalf-of-flow-aka-obo-flow/)*** . To set up the environment for OBO Flow in Python you can refer this [**Azure Sample**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-on-behalf-of).

##### OR

**You can directly use Rest to the call Graph API's from python like the below:**

```
import requests
import json
tenant_id='e186e64a-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client_secret='L~I7Q~xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client_id='1be5d8ab-1960-4508-93e4-b138b3295593'
username='admin@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
password='xxxxxxxxxxx'
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token'
token_data = {
 'grant_type': 'password',
 'client_id': client_id,
 'client_secret': client_secret,
 'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
 'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com',
 'username':username, #Account with no 2MFA
 'password':password,
}
token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
token = token_r.json().get('access_token')
# Use the token using microsoft graph endpoints
users_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
headers = {
 'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}
user_response_data = json.loads(requests.get(users_url, headers=headers).text)
print(user_response_data)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I have limited access to my computer right now but will eventually try out your solutions and report back!

Comment: sure @Salazaja, glad to be of help :)

Comment: Thanks @AnsumanBal-MT I'm able to replicate your example in your **OR** section. That is, I have successfully accessed `/me` with the `requests` library. However, for standardization, I would prefer using the `azure.identity` and `msgraph.core` libraries instead. Do you have an example like the `ClientSecretCredential` one, but using `OnbehalfOfCredential`? In the link you provided, I cannot find the snippet of code that uses the `OnbehalfOfCredential()` function. If I can confirm that part of the code first and it still doesn't work, I would ask IT to set up the app for an OBO flow.

Comment: hello @Salazaja, Onbehalf of flow will need 2 apps like frontend and backend , I have provided a sample which is provided by microsoft you can refer https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-on-behalf-of

Comment: Yes in that link I've tried searching the line that uses the `OnbehalfOfCredential()` but I cannot find it. Would you be able to pinpoint the exact file that contains that line?

Comment: I guess I misunderstand the use of `OnBehalfOfCredential()` because it does not appear to exist in that repo.